# How to show "ApexPage" object in the Org to run query all VF Pages in the org?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to run this query in my org:

```
Select Id, Name,MasterLabel﻿, ApiVersion﻿ from ApexPage
```

But it executes returning an error that ApexPage object is not available.

To confirm that, I can see `ApexClass` object in the schema browser but not `ApexPage`. Is this object not available generally to all?

If that is the case, is there any way I can query to get the List of All Visualforce Pages in the org in APEX?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that there is no queryable ApexPage.

You can use the [list Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/meta_listmetadata.htm) (including from Apex - see [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)) to get the list of pages.

Note that the pages visible to a user are filtered via profiles and permission sets.

Comment: not able to grasp the reason behind this. Just thinking if 'ApexClass' is available then why 'ApexPage' not available?

Comment: @VarunChaddha Reasonable question. Perhaps someone has an answer to that.